# Root of a polynomial in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathrm F$ be a field and $f(x)\in \mathrm F[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial. Show if $r\in \mathrm F$ such that $f(r)=0$, then $(x-r)|f(x) \in \mathrm F[x]$.

I am having a hard time visualizing how to approach this problem. I know that r will be the preimage of 0, since f(r)=0, but don't understand how to approach showing that (x-r) is a root of the polynomial.

Comment: $(x-r)$ is not a root of the polynomial, it’s a factor. The root is $r \in F$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain with the degree of the polynomial as the Euclidean function, it follows that there is a polynomial $q(x)$ and some $c\in F$ such that
$$ f(x)=(x-r)q(x)+c$$
And evaluating both sides at $x=r$ shows that $c=0$, so $x-r$ divides $f(x)$.